# Secure every endpoint ending with */private in Oracle REST-Data-Services

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-rest-data-services

I am using Oracle Rest-Data-Services to export several PL/SQL-APIs as webservice using REST. Therefore every PL/SQL-Package is an ORDS-Module and should have a template ending with `*/private` that has to be secured so only admin users can call it.

I tryed to create the following privilege.

```
DECLARE
  l_roles_arr    OWA.vc_arr;
  l_patterns_arr OWA.vc_arr;
  l_modules_arr  OWA.vc_arr;
BEGIN
  ORDS.create_role(p_role_name => 'private_role');
  l_roles_arr(1)    := 'private_role';
  l_patterns_arr(1) := '*/private';
  --  select name bulk collect into l_modules_arr from user_ords_modules;
  ORDS.define_privilege (
    p_privilege_name => 'private_priv',
    p_roles          => l_roles_arr,
    p_patterns       => l_patterns_arr,
    --p_modules        => l_modules_arr,
    p_label          => 'private',
    p_description    => 'private');
  COMMIT;
END;
```

This has no effect and unauthorized calls to `*/private` are still possible. When I uncomment the commented lines then all calls even to the other endpoints has to be authorized.

Is it posible to define a privilege pattern like this?

Comment: The [doc] (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/19.4/aelig/ORDS-reference.html#GUID-CC53F4FF-2042-4FE2-B4CA-178C9A520CF5) show all examples with a wildcard starting with a ```/```. Give ```/*/private``` a try ?

Comment: @KoenLostrie: Thanks! That was a pattern I didn't try. But it doesn't work as well.

Comment: Not sure if you can use the wildcard _before_ a string. What you could try is not use a wildcard in the _p_patterns_ argument but populate the array by looping through the ORDS_ datadictionary view

Comment: @KoenLostrie: Yes, that would work. But then I have to maintain the priviledge everytime someone adds a new module. I my case this would be a security issue. So I have to make sure, that nobody without the right role can access these endpoints.

I also think it is not possible to use wildcards this way. I only want to get sure before I open a service request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer in the api docs.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/21.3/ordjv/doc-files/route-patterns.html

> Glob Parameter
> A Glob Parameter is denoted by the wildcard Modifier (the ‘*’ character). The wildcard Modifier **MUST appear at the end** of the pattern and MUST be preceded by the path separator. Only a single Glob Parameter is permitted in a pattern. A Glob Parameter MUST NOT occur in the same pattern as a Named Parameter.

Unfortunately the wildcard `*` has to be at the end of the pattern.